# Why is smooch api rejecting any image is post as mediaUrl on post message conversation api

Tags: smooch

Here's the error message, for message type "image" and "file"

```
{"error": { "code":"invalid_file",
  "description":"File rejected. File type not allowed"}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You haven't described what exactly did you try, in what language, and how can someone else reproduce the error. Please go through the guide on [How to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for guidance on how you can improve it. This will help other people provide better assistance to you.

Answer (score 1):

Your file upload was most likely rejected because of a disallowed file extension. The whitelist of file extensions accepted by Smooch is documented [here](https://docs.smooch.io/guide/validating-files/#rejections).